# UIScrollView - Scroll Up but not down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

How do I set this UIScrollView to focus on the Selected UITextfield at specific points. I want the textfield right above the keyboard and I want to be able to scroll up but not down. My code works except for uiscrollview only lets me scroll down and not up. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        //set Y according to keyBoard height

        [self->mainScroll2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,-70.0,320.0,580.0)];
        [self->mainScroll2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,780)];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding of your case, you have a UITextfield in the `UIScrollView`, right?
If this is the case, I recommend you use the property `contentInset` of `UIScrollVIew` to "scroll up
For example:

```
float yourKeyboardHeight = 70.0;//since you are trying to change the scrollview's y to -70    
self.mainScroll2.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,yourKeyboardHeight,0);
```

This tells the `UIScrollView` to create a placeholder behind the contentView. In this code, there are four arguments for the property, it's like `UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)` I just added a bottom inset to the view so that makes the content move up 70.0 
Hope this may help